# Does Spring profile support auto-apply/auto-activate like maven profile by jdk version, OS? or how to do it easily fro deployment switching?

Tags: java, spring, maven

As we know spring can support profile since 3.1, it will help us to switch among different beans such as datasource, proxy and so on in different env. as I know profile need to be specified in web.xml or JRE system property (-D....), but Maven profile can support auto-apply profile through detecting OS or JRE version. can We do the same thing as maven supports in spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently such functionality is scheduled for `4.0  Backlog`) - [SPR-10338](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10338).

(adds `ActiveProfilesResolver` interface and `resolver` property to active profiles).

You may try to vote on jira issue to make it  be merged faster.

Currently you may try to implement custom base class for test and set system properties (which activates profiles) according some reason in constructor. But you'll require to put `@DirtiesContext` on test to not break context caching inside spring-test.